# How to get size per day of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database with ~20 tables. Each table has a column "dtLogTime" that records the time that row was inserted. I want to figure out the size (probably kb or mb) each table is recording per day. More specifically, I'm only interested in the last 3 days. Also, these tables keep track of data up to a certain time interval (i.e. 2 weeks, 1 month, etc), meaning I lose a day's worth of data for every new day's data stored.

I came across this code that can show me the size of each table.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');

$db_name = "your database name here";
$tables = array();

mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    /* We return the size in Kilobytes */
    $total_size = ($row[ "Data_length" ] + 
                   $row[ "Index_length" ]) / 1024;
    $tables[$row['Name']] = sprintf("%.2f", $total_size);
}

print_r($tables);
?>
```

When I tried doing

```
"SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE dtLogTime < '2011-08-28 00:00:00' 
AND dtLogTime >= '2011-08-27 00:00:00'"
```

it gave me an error. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: unless you really want to extract all the data to measure its size how about logging the db table files (depends on db type if this is viable) size daily. or run table status daily and log that

Comment: that sounds good, but the new rows get added in daily, so how would I log this?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[sql-server]`?

Comment: one of my colleagues suggested doing (daily number of rows) / (total number of rows) * total size of table.

anyone agree with this or have a better suggestion. seems like it will be good enough with some error

Comment: @Mark, you can perform this same action from the command line using `mysqlshow --status db_name`.  Hook this up to a CRON job that runs each day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a `LIKE` clause to specify the table. Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS 
LIKE YourTable
WHERE dtLogTime < '2011-08-28 00:00:00' 
AND dtLogTime >= '2011-08-27 00:00:00'
```

Comment: this did not work, all it did was it returned the row corresponding to YourTable. There is still no dtLogTime column

Comment: It's not going to return a dtLogTime column. It's going to return the size of the table after filtering on the WHERE clause. So if YourTable is 100MB, but the rows from 8/27-8/28 only take up 10MB, it'll return 10MB.

Comment: hmmm, it gave me an error that it didn't know what dtLogTime was. My bad on the last comment, I meant that I had run SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE YourTable and that just returned the row corresponding to YourTable. I'm assuming this is why the WHERE clause still did not work

Comment: @Derek SHOW TABLE STATUS is a convenience method to interrogate `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, it does no computation on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` clause applies to the resulting table generated by `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, and cannot be actual columns of your various tables.  For instance:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS where Index_length = 0
```

Run `SHOW TABLE STATUS` by itself to see a list of all the legal columns you can use in the `WHERE` clause.  Unfortunately, for your situation, you'll have to run `SHOW TABLE STATUS` each day and store the result somewhere.

**UPDATE**

For clarification, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is a convenience method that interrogates the system table, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.  It will pare down the results from that system table to just the persistent tables in your current database.  It doesn't perform any calculations of its own.

Comment: thanks, so just to confirm, do SHOW TABLE STATUS today, record the sizes of each table. Then do SHOW TABLE STATUS tomorrow, and use the difference as the daily size. Is that right?

Comment: You got it.  :-)  You might want to actually record the size of your Index_length along with you data_length, as they both will contribute to your physical growth on the hard drive.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention these tables delete data each day. As an example, one of the tables will keep track of data 2 weeks back. Hence, I will lose a day's worth of data for every new day's worth of data, so SHOW TABLE STATUS should return similar results each day (as opposed to increasing)

Comment: Ah.  I gotcha.  I do similar archiving for some of my databases, and this technique is useful to create a threshold to trigger archiving (e.g., back up and delete half the rows if the storage space exceeds 100 MB).